# How can I check if all values in an array have a certain value?

Tags: java, arrays, traversal

In Java, given an array of values (say integers), is there a way to efficiently check to see if they all have a certain value?

For example, with an array of integers such as:

```
int[] numbers = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
```

and you need to perform an action only if all of them are 2, is there a more effective way than doing this:

```
if (numbers[1] == 2 && numbers[2] == 2 && numbers[3] == 2 && …)
```

I know there are ways to do this in C++ but what about Java?

Comment: You definitely should use a loop or a stream function to write something like this.  If you're asking about _effciency_, however, you really can't do better than comparing each number until you find one that isn't 2.  If you use a stream function, however, the program _might_ be able to divide your array into segments and assign each segment to a different core on a multicore system.  On average this should be faster, depending on your platform, but it might be slower in cases where one of the first elements of the array is something other than 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or, if using java 8, you can do something like:

```
if(Arrays.stream(numbers).allMatch(x -> x == 2)) {
    // do something
}
```

Basically, pretty much everything that you might want to do that deals with collections/arrays, can be very concisely done with the [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Comment: @Andreas that's of course okay, and probably better for the OP :)

Comment: An approach that doesn't rely on any specific value is `Arrays.stream(numbers).distinct().count() <= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean AreAllEqual(int[] numbers) {
    for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(numbers[0] != numbers[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Using a function here will save you a lot of coding time and will also allow you to pass in arrays of arbitrary sizes (because you are iterating through the array according to its length).